# Make multipoly only if two field values overlap?

Tags: qgis

So I want to combine all the polygons that share two different attribute values and don't really know where to start.

[image]

The selection shows you my problem, they both have the same classification (890) and belong to the same block (third column). I want these (and all other similar occurences) to be considered a single multipart polygon. How?

The regular singlepart to multipart tool won't do me any good since I will loose either classification field or the block id field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Dissolve` geoprocessing tool:

> **Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve...**

Then, specify the column on which to merge polygons (in your case: `JG2`).

I did the test and it works good, you do preserve your 3 columns.

If you want to merge polygons based on 2 columns only, then concatenate the content of the two columns in a new one (string type) and use the `Dissolve` tool on this new column. This can be done easily with the **Field Calculator** using the following expression:

```
"JG2" || '_' || "Blockid"
```

Comment: The problem with your first answer is the same as with doing single part to multi part. Yes I do get to keep all the columns, but the values in those columns get thrown away.


But the string concatenation thing did just what I tried to do! Thanks!

Comment: I did not get values thrown away problem with `Dissolve` tool... (?)